# ¿Cómo actualizar php en ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: php, ubuntu, xampp

El problema que tengo es que no se como actualizar la versión de php de mi pc.

Intenté actualizar con los siguientes comandos:

```
    -sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
    -sudo apt upgrade
    -php -v
```

Pero cuando ejecuto php -v, el mensaje que aparece es **PHP 7.0.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.16 (cli) ( NTS )**

Y cuando verifico en XAMPP, la versión que aparece es PHP Version 8.0.1.

¿Hay alguna forma de que tanto ubuntu como XAMPP tengan la misma versión de php?

Answer (score 1):

Después de agregar el repositorio PPA, debes hacer 
`sudo apt-get update` 
`sudo apt-get update php8.0` 
PD: Es posible que tengas que instalar otros componentes. 
Luego puedes cambiar a la version 8 con el siguiente comando 
`sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php8.0` 
 
Y para activar la version 8 en Apache 
`sudo a2enmod php8.0`

Comment: No funcionó. Me salta este error "E: La orden de actualización no necesita argumentos"

Comment: revisa que hayas puesto bien el comando, como puedes ver arriba, el comando no tiene argumentos. Tambien puedes probar con `sudo apt update`